# Preg_match with different combinations of words

Tags: php, preg-match, substr

I've a littile question about preg_matches, these regex things are really hard to understand and I hope someone can give the right awnser!

I have the following text:

```
0A-24-423
```

But this can also be:

```
0A-242-2
```

or

```
0A-2-423
```

How can I use preg_matches to filter these? I was using

```
substr($something, 0,2)
```

so that it captures 0A and

```
substr($seat, 4,5)
```

This will capture 24 but when you get 242 it wont capture the last 2....

Hope someone can help creating this in preg_match!

to make it more clear what I have now:

```
        foreach($_POST['seats'] AS $seat) {
        if ($count > 0) {
            $selectQuery .= " || ";
        }
        $selectQuery .= " ( rowId = '" . substr($seat, 0,2) . "'";
        $selectQuery .= " and `order` = " . substr($seat, 3,5) . "  ";
        $selectQuery .= " and columnId = " . substr($seat, 6) . " ) ";
        $count++;
```

and $seat had the following format XXXXXX and using substr I can get the right things (for example: 0J3017)

Something Like this should do it:

```
    $selectQuery = "SELECT * from seats where ";
    $count = 0;
$pattern = "I DON'T KNOW :( ";
    foreach($_POST['seats'] AS $seat) {
        if ($count > 0) {
            $selectQuery .= " || ";
        }
        preg_match($pattern, $seats, $matches);
        $selectQuery .= " ( rowId = '" . $matches[0] . "'";
        $selectQuery .= " and `order` = " . $matches[1] . "  ";
        $selectQuery .= " and columnId = " . $matches[2] . " ) ";
        $count++;
```

and $seats is explained in the beginning of the post (it has a format of `XX-XXX-XXX`

```
where the first 2 XX  are 0[A-Z] (yes the 0 is correct)
where the 3 first XXX are [0-9]
Where the last 3  XXX are [0-9]
```

EDIT:
there are 2 ways to solve this.

Option 1:

```
$pattern = "/(.*)-(.*)-(.*)/";
```

or use explode() function.

Comment: Thanks for the mark up (sorry). I haven't really tried anything because I don't understand a thing about regexes.... I read some articles but that is really unclear to me...

Comment: @user1939649 same as me :) but can you explain your question more what type of filtering?

Comment: Well like I said, I've a php script that gets information from a javascript post in the following formats
0A-24-423
But this can also be:
0A-242-2
or
0A-2-423

First I just had 1 format:
A-2-2
and I just substr for this, but now I have these different kind of input formats (dynamicly generated!) I have to use preg_matches (atleast that is what I could find to replace substr)

Comment: one minute can you explain what is 0A and 242 and 423? i can help you!

Comment: @Aspiring Aqib I have updated the first post

Comment: again I updated the first code with what I think it should but but I don't know how to create the pattern...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not look like you need to be using regular expressions. Here's an example using [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) and [`list()`](http://php.net/list):

```
list($row_id, $order, $column_id) = explode('-', $seat, 3);
```

You could then use those three new variables in your `$selectQuery`.

Comment: Dude you rock! Totaly forgot the explode() functions, thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT :** Since the OP has stated his requirement as a comment to my answer I have updated my answer accordingly.

You can try this:

```
$pattern = "/[A-Z\d]{1,2}-[A-Z\d]{1,3}-[A-Z\d]{1,3}/";
$matched = preg_match($pattern, $something);
if ($matched === 0) {
  die('regex did not match');
}
```

`$matched` will give you `1` for a matched string and `0` if *not* matched.

Comment: Thanks for the pattern, I'm not a english speaker so explain it is a little hard ;)

It's dynamicly, you can interperated the input as followed:
XX-XXX-XXX
where XX would be replaced by either numbers or characters (ABCDEFG etc)

I updated the first post with hopfully the right explanation

Comment: @user1939649 Updated my answer according to the comment.